Flow Map generator for water effect in three.js
I am developing a project on three.js. I need to realize the effect of water flow; for this, I want to use Flow Map. Can you please tell me what generators are used to create such maps so that I can use them (i.e., a Flow Maps) in three.js?
Here's an example of the effect
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_water_flowmap.html
Click on the Show Flow Map checkbox on the top right and you will see the flow map itself with the colors of the water flow direction. This is the map I want to create.
For example, there is an addon for Blender called Flow Map Painter. It takes into account the speed of the cursor when drawing, adds the appropriate color and immediately shows the result - how the water will flow. This is the convenience of such a generator, as opposed to just drawing in Photoshop or wherever.
But where to draw such a map for use in three.js?

Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean?

@Łukasz I supplemented the question.
